# How to get the current session name in Drools Rule RHS

Tags: drools

I have tried searching through the various levels of indirection of both 'drools' and 'kcontext', but seem to keep running into a wall. Is there a way I can get access to the current session name in a RHS of a rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "session name" is used as a handle for retrieving the session model from the container. It isn't a property of KieSession.

It's easy to use a global containing the session name:

```
String sessionName = ...;
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession( sessionName );
kSession.setGlobal( "sessionName", sessionName );
```

DRL

```
global String sessionName;
```

This might be improved by adding the creation date/time or anything else that identifies session *instances* (as opposed to session model).

Comment: That is what I have done, but wanted to check if I had not missed a path via which the information was already available.